# NoClassDefFound error for Xerces lib StreamSource class

Tags: java, android, buildpath

I get the following error at runtime:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mf/javax/xml/transform/stream/StreamSource

from this line of code:

```
Source schemaFile = new StreamSource(XSDreader);
```

this is the first occurence of a Xerces class instance in the code.

1. I downloaded *Xerces for Android* from Google code.
2. Imported the code as a new *Java project* in Eclipse
3. Exported a JAR file from the Xerces project (compiled OK)
4. Added the Xerces JAR file to my project build path libraries
5. In the code I changed all `import` lines  from `javax...` to `mf.javax...`

Checked the .jar file and it contains the class StreamSource in the expected path
Tried to add Xerces/bin to the classpath (it has the .class files), but this did not help.
Cleaned the project, it did not help either.
Checked my project and Xerces projects use the same JDK compliance version (1.7)

Debugged the code and got to the point where `VMClassLoader` does not find the class, could not dig deeper than this.

At this point I ran out of ideas.

Comment: I think Android projects and libs used in those should use JDK 1.6. Jars files compiled with 1.7 are common causes of NoClassDefFoundError as classes compiled with 1.7 are not packaged into apk file.

Comment: @Lecho I tried your suggestion and it does not solve the problem.

Comment: "Added the Xerces JAR file to my project build path libraries" -- undo that, then put the JAR in `libs/`, like you do with any other JAR when using Eclipse for Android development. "Tried to add Xerces/bin to the classpath" -- undo that too.

Comment: @CommonWare that worked. Now I am stucked on "www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" not recognized a a valid schema by the SchemaFinder, but that's stuff for another, separate, question

Answer (score 0):

For a simple solution see @CommonsWare comment to the question. That solution works fine, the only problem is that when debugging, the debugger cannot follow the code into the library and Eclipse does not offer the option to specify where the sources are.
So after some trial and error I found another solution that does allow to debug the library code as well.

1. Open your project Build Path configuration
2. Under Libraries choose "Add Library..."

   2.1 Select the type "User Library" and click next.

   2.2 Click "User Libraries..."

   2.3 Add a new library, name it as you wish. It will be created empty

   2.4 Select "Add JAR file" and browse and choose the xerces JAR file.

   2.5 Click the "Source attachment" line and point it to the src folder of xerces.

   2.6 OK all back to the Build path dialog.
3. Go to the "Order and Export" tab and mark the new library checked.